# How can I pass POST parameters in fetch request? - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, post, request

This is my code:

```
componentWillMount() {
  fetch("http://localmachine/localservice/webservice/rest/server.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      wstoken: 'any_token',
      wsfunction: 'any_function',
      moodlewsrestformat: 'json',
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pass',
    })
  })
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseText) => {
    alert(responseText);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

In the browser, this request returns a token, but in my react-native android App returns a xml error.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This what worked for me

```
fetch("http://10.4.5.114/localservice/webservice/rest/server.php", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
    }),
  body: "param1=value1&param2=value2" // <-- Post parameters
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseText) => {
  alert(responseText);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: and how to pass variable with parameter in body

Answer (score 17):

Try to add header in post request.

```
       headers: {
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',

       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
         wstoken: 'any_token',
         wsfunction: 'any_function',
         moodlewsrestformat: 'json',
         username: 'user',
         password: 'pass',
      })
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the JSON.stringify when adding parameters to the body.

Comment: Adding json headers is a better solution.