# React Native Make a POST request

Tags: json, react-native, post, parameters, fetch

I am trying to perform a post request using `fetch`.

My request looks like this:

```
fetch(RequestURL,
{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body:
    "param1=" + this.state.variable1 +
    "param2=" + this.state.variable2 +
    "param3=" + this.state.variable3 +
    "param4=" + variable1+
    "param5=" + variable2+
    "param6=" + variable3
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(obj =>  {
  callback(obj)
})
.catch((error) => {
  //Do some stuff.
})
```

`requestURL` could be something like `www.example.com\file\example.php`

I have tried the solution suggested here:

> [How can i pass POST parameters in fetch request? - React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011100/how-can-i-pass-post-parameters-in-fetch-request-react-native)
>   This did not work for me. DId I just miss something or is it because I am using JSON for my response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not passed params correctly in body. This can be achieved by two ways as follows:

1] Adding '&' in body params as follows:

```
"param1=" + this.state.variable1 +
"&param2=" + this.state.variable2 +
"&param3=" + this.state.variable3 +
"&param4=" + variable1+
"&param5=" + variable2+
"&param6=" + variable3
```

Or

2] There is another way to do so by adding below code to body:

```
JSON.stringify({
     param1: this.state.variable1,
     param2: this.state.variable2,
     param3: this.state.variable3,
     param4: variable1,
     param5: variable2,
     param6: variable3
})
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out.**

```
body: JSON.stringify(payload)
```

Payload is your json object.